# Addition and multiplication of two numbers.

Tags: arithmetic

At this point I have to find out the maximum number of digits I can get when I multiply 2 numbers with `m` and `n` digits. I am not able to find the generalized solution for multiplication and addition. There might exist a very simple formula but I couldn't any. I googled but couldn't find any relevant topic I may have searched with wrong keyword.

Thanks In Advance

Dibya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  what is the largest number with $m$ digits?  It is just less than a power of $10$.  Express it that way and multiply it by the largest number with $n$ digits.  You might try $m=2, n=3$ with your calculator to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks

Comment: I got a pattern for multiplication. It is `M+N` but couldn't find one for addition. Can you please help me here?

Comment: When you add two numbers, the most you can carry is $1$